# ScriptSharp jQueryApi.inArray implementation difference (bug in scriptsharp?)

Tags: script#

jquery documentation defines its inArray function as follows:

> jQuery.inArray( value, array )
>
> Returns: Number
>
> Description: Search
>   for a specified value within an array
>   and return its index (or -1 if not
>   found).

scriptsharp's equivalent function:

> public static bool InArray(object
>   value, System.Array a)
>
> ```
> Member of jQueryApi.jQuery
> ```
>
> Summary:
>   Gets the index of the specified value within the specified array.

Even the summary of the function tells it should return a number (the index), but the method's return type is bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in an incremental build that should come out shortly.

For bugs, the better reporting channel would be the issue list on github (http://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp), while stack overflow would be better for Q&A/discussion.

Speaking of github, the sources for Script.jQuery.dll are shared, so you can fork and fix on your end if you're blocked, and until the fix has been implemented/released.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I get the github source code to compile? I can see there is a Setup.bat and clean.bat file but it is unclear how to get these to work correctly (sorry for noob question!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719977/script-getting-the-latest-build-to-compile