# Script# - Getting the latest build to compile

Tags: compilation, script#

I've downloaded (cloned the repository) of script# from https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp

Only I can't figure out how to get the source to compile.

I have installed ScriptSharp 0.7.3.0 as it seems to have a dependency on the installed directory to be present in the build.

I have looked around in the source code for some instructions and on google to no success.

### Edit

Seems that the Libraries won't compile for me.
In particular the CoreLib is requesting the a reference to 'mscorlib' be added

BTW I really recommend using script# for complex projects with rich web client experiences.
Especially coupled with knockout.js

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem compiling the whole solution. (v 0.7.3) In fact the CoreLib project seems not having any external reference at all. (CoreLib compiles to mscorlib.dll). You could try to download the complete source package again, open and compile the ScriptSharp solution.

Comment: CoreLib **IS** the missing reference as it compiles as 'mscorlib'

Comment: Maybe I will install a VM with a clean copy of VS2010 and see if it works there

Comment: I still can't get the source to compile :(